# Anyone doing or done any A/B or multivariate testing with SharePoint 2007/2010

Tags: testing, audience-targeting

How easy or hard is it to spit out two pages running concurrently (or more pages if we do multivariate tests)?

We're using SP 2010.

We'd need a way to easily:

- *generate* these pages
- *modify* these pages (for the tests) and
- possibly *archive* the pages when all is said and done.

We’d possibly also want to exclude the testing pages (and any archive) from being indexed in the SP search as well.

Modifying the pages seems like it might be a sticky spot as depending on the test, you might have to modify the structure of the page a little and that would mean you’d need to modify the webparts.  I don’t think we’d want to do that until a test has proven itself and we wanted to roll out a permanent change.

We might be able to hack it a bit by viewing the source code of the test page (the A page) in a browser and modify that code manually for the B page, but would we possibly lose any dynamic functionality on that page by this manual tweaking of the source?  Could we just upload a page created in this fashion as well (after changing all links/images/resources file paths/references)?

Also, we’d need to somehow split the traffic amongst the pages we’re testing (50% to page A, 50% to page B in a simple case), is that easily achieved?

Anyone ever done this?

As a FYI, I'm not a SP developer so my first-hand SP knowledge is limited.

Comment: it's beyond me why this is too localized, should anybody want more information or a place to discuss this further: http://www.quora.com/Which-A-B-testing-tools-can-be-used-on-a-Sharepoint-Intranet

Answer (score 0):

The splitting of the traffic is typically handled by the analytics tool like google analytics after you have done all the page reference tagging necessary.

It'd be interesting to know if others have learned how well that works with dynamic functionality like the content query web part.